# WPF DatePicker textbox white border not editable

Tags: wpf, xaml, datepicker, textbox, controltemplate

I am editing the control template for the `DatePicker` but there is an issue with the `TextBox` style. There is a white border around the text which IS NOT the actual `TextBox` border.
With my current style, I have the `TextBox` inside a `Border` with the `TextBox` `Background` set to transparent and the `BorderThickness` set to 0.

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" 
        Height="25"
        Background="DarkKhaki"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1">

<DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   BorderThickness="0"
                   Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                   Margin="1.143,0,1.056,0"/>
                            </Border>
```

This is what the `DatePicker` looks like with this Style:

[image: raw]

If I add a `Border` to the `TextBox`, it appears around the white `Border`:

[image: bordered]

If anyone has any idea on how to remove this extra `Border` it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new `Style` for the `DatePickerTextBox`:

#### XAML Style

This is just a copy of the original `Style` and changed the `Visibility` of the two `Border` to `Hidden`.

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerTextBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">


<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="VerticalFirst"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WatermarkBrush" Color="#FFAAAAAA"/>
                            </Grid.Resources>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF99C1E2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="watermark_decorator"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="WatermarkStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unwatermarked"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Watermarked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Watermark"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="1" Opacity="1" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                    <Border x:Name="ContentElement" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Hidden"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Hidden">
                                        <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisual" BorderBrush="#FF45D6FA" CornerRadius="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

#### XAML

```
    <Border
        Background="DarkKhaki" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        CornerRadius="5">
        <DatePickerTextBox 
            x:Name="datePickerTextBox" 
            Height="25" 
            Width="120" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            Text="DatePickerTextBox" 
            Background="Transparent"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"                 
            Style="{DynamicResource DatePickerTextBoxStyle1}"/>
    </Border>
```

#### Preview

[image: Preview]

If you create a new `Style` you can also include your "Khaki" `Border` with the `CornerRadius`.

---

**Thanks @OfficeAddinDev**

*This answer removes the border by setting the "watermark_decorator" Border. `Visibility = Hidden`. Simply change this to `Visible` and change `BorderThickness = 0` instead to show "Select a date" without the menacing white border.*

Comment: Thanks for this! Though I set the two borders to visible and changed the BorderThickness to 0 instead otherwise the 'Select a date' text isn't visible.

Comment: This answer removes the border by setting the "watermark_decorator" Border.Visibility = Hidden.  Simply change this to Visible and change BorderThickness = 0 instead to show "Select a date" without the menacing white border.

Comment: @OfficeAddinDev thank you for your answer! I have added your solution 

Answer (score 1):

> There is a white border around the text which IS NOT the actual TextBox border

Yes, it is. The `Border` is part of the `DatePickerTextBox`'s default control template.

If you don't want it you will have override the template as suggested by @Dominic Jonas. You should just be able to get rid of the two inner `Border` elements that both have a hardcoded `BorderThickness` of `1`:

```
<Border Grid.Column="0" 
        Height="25"
        Background="DarkKhaki"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="1">
    <DatePickerTextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" 
                   Background="Transparent"
                   Grid.Column="0" 
                   BorderThickness="0"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                   Grid.Row="0" 
                   Grid.ColumnSpan="1" 
                   Margin="1.143,0,1.056,0">
        <DatePickerTextBox.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="WatermarkContent" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PART_Watermark" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Padding="2"/>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </DatePickerTextBox.Template>
    </DatePickerTextBox>
</Border>
```